# change docker datetime inside container

Tags: docker, datetime

I have code that builds and runs tests on a pool of build machines.  Most importantly - that pool is owned and operated by people in the larger company - I have no control over the machines, and no direct access to the people who do.

The time on some of the machines is out of sync, by sometimes up to 10 minutes.   Unfortunately - that's well and truly enough for my tests to fail, as the amazon api rejects the calls, because of the invalid timestamp.

The thing is though - the tests are running inside a docker container.  So I think fine, I'll just sync the time inside the container and I'll be fine.  So I come up with this:

```bash
date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g')"
```

and just get:

```
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
```

I then tried:

```bash
apt-get install -y ntp
ntpd -q -g
```

which just eventually times out - even if I give the task 10 minutes to run.

now... I *thought* that the docker container had its own sense of time - or at least a way of having an offset from the system time... but maybe not?

Is there any way of solving this problem?  Anything to do with changing/fixing the outside machine - while ideal - is just not an option, as it's not even close to being in my control.

I've done a lot of googling and found lots of people talking about changing the *timezone* inside of docker - but I do not want the timezone changed - just want skew fixed.

Comment: yes - it appears to be impossible without making a new image :(